# Spring Security OAuth2 MultipartRequest with android

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using:

- Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE
- Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE
- spring-security-oauth2 1.0.0.RELEASE

I have created a two multipart request:

One is at Non-secure controller Second at a Secure controller.
Both are same, there is no change.

**Non secured request works very fine but secured Multipart request not working**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/profileimage", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String createProfilePicture(@RequestParam MultipartFile 
file, @RequestParam String profileId){
}
```

Please reply if you require more information.

Comment: You have an error on secured controller ? Which one ? you have other secured endpoint working fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what exactly you are trying to achieve by implementing an oauth2 authorization server.
Do you plan to support various authentication providers e.g Facebook, Linkedin, Google?

Please specify the error message you get when trying to consume the API.

Please share your Security configuration classes i.e the class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and any other configuration that you have.

You can review [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) article which details how to implement an oauth2 authorization server to make sure you haven't missed any part.

In regards to the code above, it seems corrent but can be simplified:

```
@PostMapping("/profileimage")
public @ResponseBody String createProfilePicture(@RequestParam MultipartFile 
file, @RequestParam String profileId){
}
```

You can even drop the `@ResponseBody` annotation in case a `@RestController` 
annotation is specified on the class.

Good luck!